# How to encrypt strings in python without a python package

Tags: python, string, encryption, server

I need to encrypt singular strings, and store them for later use as text files. Desired output:

```
Enter string: I like to eat muffins
Enter decryption password: password12345
Enter save name: muffin
```

Then retrieving the data:

```
file: muffin
password: password12345
str: I like to eat muffins
```

I need to save all of that information as an encrypted text file without using any prebuilt packages. I also need a way to decrypt the text file and prompt the user for the pre entered password. The file would look like a random array of numbers and characters, and all of the information that was entered in above would be stored in it, so that it could b sent to another person with the same program and they would have to have the password(which is stored in the file) to read it.

Comment: OK, that's not a hard task.  What have you done so far?

Comment: What type of encryption are you looking to implement? What have you tried?

Comment: my problem is that I cannot use any pre built encryption modules, like fernet.

Comment: i do not even know if this is possible.

Comment: [Are you aware of the grave security risks of trying to roll your own cryptography suite?](https://resources.infosecinstitute.com/topic/the-dangers-of-rolling-your-own-encryption/) Why can't you use anything pre-built (and thereby likely provably mathematically secure)?? Seems like quite an arbitrary requirement to me, unless you're a team of cryptographers/researchers well-versed in the nuances required to perform such a task in a completely secure manner. In any event, what have you written thus far? We most certainly aren't going to design/implement an encryption scheme entirely *for* you.

Comment: @esqew I promise I'll never eat again pemmican if the OP's intent is rolling their own cryptography suite.

Comment: @esqew this is simply something for in program content, none of the encrypted data is going to be published or sent anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you are just looking for some simple encryption to demonstrate the concepts, and not something as sophisticated as a modern, safe cryptographic suite.

This code does simple xor encryption between your clear text and your key.  This is easily crackable, given enough text, but it shows the concepts.

```
import sys

def encode():
    cleartext = input("Enter string: ")
    key = input("Enter decryption password: ")
    filename = input("Enter save name: ")

    reps = (len(cleartext)-1)//len(key) +1

    a1 = cleartext.encode('utf-8')
    key = (key * reps)[:len(cleartext)].encode('utf-8')
    cipher = bytes([i1^i2 for (i1,i2) in zip(a1,key)])
    open(filename,'wb').write(cipher)


def decode():
    key = input("Enter decryption password: ")
    filename = input("Enter save name: ")

    cipher = open(filename,'rb').read()
    reps = (len(cipher)-1)//len(key) +1
    key = (key * reps)[:len(cipher)].encode('utf-8')
    clear = bytes([i1^i2 for (i1,i2) in zip(cipher,key)])
    return clear.decode('utf-8')

if sys.argv[1] == "-d":
    print(decode())
elif sys.argv[1] == '-e':
    encode()
else:
    print("What?")
```

Comment: I was writing up an answer but Tim beat me to it. When starting out with cryptography, understanding the language is important. [Here is a good resource](https://web.mit.edu/Saltzer/www/publications/protection/index.html) with common terms and their definitions.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. thank you so much @Tim Roberts

Comment: When I used `"èèèèèèè0123456789"` as the clear text, and `"a"` as the password. what I got back is `"èèèèèèè012"`. I wonder if you need to convert everything (clear text & password) to `bytes` before computing `reps`.

Comment: True.  As an American, I automatically assume all ASCII characters.  ;)